# Is monotonicity hold of a continuous vector function across union of sets?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, monotone-functions

A vector function $F$ is monotonic in $S_i$ if
$$
(F(x)-F(y))^T (x-y)\geq 0, \forall x,y\in S_i.
$$

However, I am unsure if this property holds for continuous functions when considering the union of the sets, i.e., if a continuous vector function is monotonic in $S_1, S_2, \dots, S_n$ respectively, is it monotonic in the whole $\cup_{i=1}^n S_i$?

Comment: Hello, just to be sure, what exactly are the $S_i$ ?

Comment: @NaNoS A subset of the domain of $F$.

Comment: @NaNoS For example, I know a function is monotonic in $\{(x,y): x+y\leq 1\}$ and $\{(x,y): x+y\geq 1\}$ {respectively}, but how about the $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without additional assumptions about the domain of $F$, the answer is **no**. For example, if $S_1 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 ~;~ x < -1\}$, $S_2 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 ~;~ 1 < x\}$ and $U = S_1 \cup S_2$, you can see that

$$F(x,y) = \begin{cases}(1,0) & \text{if } (x,y) \in S_1 \\
(-1,0) & \text{if } (x,y) \in S_2
\end{cases}$$

is continuous on $U$ and monotonic on $S_1$ and $S_2$. Now if you take $v \in S_1$ and $w \in S_2$, you have $F(w) - F(v) = (-2,0)$ and the first coordinate of the vector $w - v$ is positive so $F$ is not monotonic on $U$. Of course it works because $U$ is not a connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$.

If now $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ is a connected subset and $F : U \to \mathbb R^n$ is your continuous function, I have to think about it.

**Edit :** $S_1 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 ; (x+1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$, $S_2 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 ; (x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$, and $U$ is the union of these two circles. You can see that $U$ is path-connected. Define

$$F(x,y) = \begin{cases}(y,-x) & \text{if } (x,y) \in S_1 \\
(-y,x) & \text{if } (x,y) \in S_2
\end{cases}$$
$F$ is the rotation of angle $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ on $S_1$ while it is the rotation of angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$ on $S_2$ (both with center $(0,0)$). Now $F$ is well-defined, continous and monotonic on $S_1$ and $S_2$. Observe that
$$\Big(F\big((1,1)\big) - F\big((-2,0)\big)\Big)^T \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = -4 < 0$$
Because $(1,1) \in S_2$ and $(-2,0) \in S_1$, we see that $F$ is not monotonic on $U$.

I’ll let you handle the case where $U$ is convex.

**Edit:** For convex *U*, we have:

If a vector-valued continuous function ${F}$ is monotonic in separated sets $U_i, i=1,\dots,n$ of a convex domain $U$ respectively, then it is monotonic in the whole domain $U$.

*Proof.*
For any two points $x_1, x_K\in U$, by convexity of $U$, we suppose the segment between them (i.e., $\{\theta x_1 + (1-\theta)x_K| \theta\in [0,1]\}$) is crossed with boundaries of $U_k$ at $x_k = \theta_k x_1 + (1-\theta_k)x_K, k=2,\dots,K-1$ respectively. Without loss of generality, we consider $\theta_k < \theta_{k-1}$.

By the definition of monotonicity of vector-valued functions over $U_k$, we have
$$
    [F(x_k) - F(x_{k-1})]^T (x_k - x_{k-1}) \geq 0,
$$
which means
$$
    [F(x_k) - F(x_{k-1})]^T (\theta_k - \theta_{k-1}) (x_1 - x_K)\geq 0.
$$
Since $\theta_k < \theta_{k-1}$, we have
$$
    [F(x_k) - F(x_{k-1})]^T (x_1 - x_K)\leq 0.
$$
By summing over $k$ from $2$ to $K$, we obtain
$$
    [F(x_K) - F(x_{1})]^T (x_1 - x_K)\leq 0,
$$
which proves the monotonicity of $F$ over $U$.

Comment: In your example, if $x\geq 1$, the function is not monotonic by definition.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I was confused because the definition of a monotonic function in this case does not coincide with the usual notion for real values functions. I made an edit and made a partial answer. If I have the time to think more about it, I will try to write a complete answer.

Comment: Waiting for your answer for connected $U$.

Comment: See my second edit.

Comment: I've edited your answer to consider the case where $U$ is convex.